# Cannot access MVC app on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

How can i access MVC  views in Localhost ?. I have deployed my **MVC 2** application on IIS 7 using VS 2010 my url address is **localhost/MyApp** but i cannot access the views .

I have tried `localhost/MyApp/Views/User/logon`  but i get **404.0 error**

My web config is as follows

```
              <appSettings>
                   <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
                   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
              </appSettings>
              <system.webServer>
                   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
                   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
              </system.webServer>

             <runtime>
               <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                   <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
                   </dependentAssembly>
              </assemblyBinding>
            </runtime>
```

**Routing Code**

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I tried,

1 )To test I added **default.aspx** page in my root folder and it works fine

2)  I ran aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: Can you try http://localhost/MyApp/User/logon

Comment: MVC urls are by default `{controller}/{action}`... Could you please post your routing code?

Comment: Side note: I've changed `MVC` tag to `ASP.Net-MVC`, please edit if you feel it is wrong change (and provide information on what MVC framework you use instead).

Comment: Even if you have pages in the views that must be updated in the controller. I guess you havent updated in the controller so getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get content from either

- routed Urls like `"MyApp/Home/Index"` or maybe `"MyApp/User/Logon"` if you have `UserController` with an action called `Logon`.
- direct urls to physical files like `"MyApp/default.aspx"`, `"MyApp/image/image1.png"` or maybe even views `"MyApp/Views/User/Logon.aspx"` (I'm not sure about last one, default config may blocks direct rendering of files from Views folder).

Other urls (like you tried) should correctly return `404` : there is no route to `Views` and no physical file without extension (unless you put one there).

Comment: I tried all the possible ways but I am getting same 404.0 error